# How to schedule task to run every 10 minutes, from 8:00 to 15:00 on multiple days of week (with schtask.exe)?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line-interface, task-scheduler

How to schedule a task to run every 10 minutes, from 8:00 to 15:00 on multiple days of week, i.e. on Mon,Tue,Wed?

The task I described can be defined with the GUI of Task Scheduler by using the 'Advanced' button in the 'Schedule' tab in the task Properties window. Is it possible to define the same task with one schtasks command? If yes, how would the command look like? If not, what would be the workaround.

Here is an example picture:

[image]

All the fields in the 'Advanced' window are similar to the Minute schedule type. Yet from what I've tested, it appears that I can't define two schedule types in one command (i.e. Minute + Weekly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is done through using commas to separate the /d command:

```
schtasks /sc Weekly /tn Backups /d mon,wed,fri /tr [command]
```

Similar to that.

As for the "repeat every X minutes between Y and Z" portion, I'm afraid that can't be done from the `schtasks` in Windows XP. In Vista and higher they added this functionality. The above screen would be written as:

`schtasks /Create /tn Runthings /tr C:\tasks\runthings.cmd /sc Weekly /d mon,tue,weds /st 08:00 /et 15:00 /ri 10`

Comment: sysadmin1138: thanks for the response. I have already known about the /d mon,wed,fri syntax and the command you've provided is a valid part of the solution. I've asked because I can't figure out the second part (8:00 - 15:00 every 10 mins).

Comment: ..., so both parts would work together in one command.

Answer (score 2):

When options get a bit complicated, an alternative may be to manually create the task using the GUI  with the configuration that you need, export it to an XML file, then use the command: `SCHTASKS /CREATE /XML <fileName>` to create a task on a target computer.

```
/XML  xmlfile      Creates a task from the task XML specified in a file.
                   Can be combined with /RU and /RP switches, or with /RP
                   alone, when task XML already contains the principal.
```

Note that creating tasks from XML files are useful for other purposes, such as if you wanted to adjust the base priority of a task process.

Comment: Unfortunately /xml switch is not supported on Windows XP. Thanks for the response though.